# If match found then add to dictionary, otherwise perform a process extract one fuzz match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I have a 2 dataframes that Im comparing and then adding the results to a dictionary.

I can get the first batch of results to work but when I add in the else statement thats when things go bad

Right now, it appears to run forever.  Im new to dictionaries and looping through dataframes.

Here's my code so far (and please note that it doesnt work) :

**Also please note that Im using the tuple output of process.extract (address, score, index) and I created a separate dataframe that Im matching on the index and taking the value of that index and putting it as a item in my dictionary.**

Here's my variables:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=['Address1','Type'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 3)), columns=['Address2','Type', 'ID']) (I want to grab the ID from this DF)
id_match = df['ID'].to_dict()
resultstest= defaultdict(list)
matched = [process.extract(i,df2['Address_2'], limit=1)[0] for i in df1['Address_1']]
```

df2 has aprox 80k rows &
df1 has ~50 rows

Here's the code:

```
for lrow in df1.itertuples():
    for vrow in df2.itertuples():
        if lrow.Address_1 == vrow.Address_2:
            resultstest[lrow.Address_PSL].append({'ID' : vrow._1, 'Address_match': vrow.Address_2,
                                             'Sales' : vrow._6, 'Calls': vrow._7, 'Target': vrow._8,
                                             'Type': vrow._5})
            break #match found done
        else:              
            for z, y in id_match.items():
                for m in matched:
                    if z == m[2] :#matching on*indexs*
                        print(z)
                        resultstest[lrow.Address_1].append({' ID' : y, 'Address_match': m[0](score, \
                                                          'Fuzz_Score': m[1]}) 
                        break
#m[0] is the address, m[1] is the score
```

My output would be something like this:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'address xyz': [{' ID': '1111111',
               'Address_match': 'address xyz',
               'Sales': nan,
               'Calls': nan,
               'Target': 0.0,
               'ID_Type': 'X'}],
            {'address abc': [{' ID': '11112222',
               'Address_match': 'address abc',
               'Sales': nan,
               'Calls': nan,
               'Target': 0.0,
               'ID_Type': 'Y'}],
             {'address xyz12345':[{'ID': '1231569',
               'Address_match': 'address xyz12345',
               'Fuzz_Score': 97}]})
```

Comment: Please add complete suitable code. The code given is not working properly.
```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2]], columns=['Address', 'Type'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2], [3]], columns=['Address', 'Type', 'ID'])
```
The above code is giving `ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns`

Comment: I fixed it so at least you can pull in generic dataframes now.